# Popup displaying on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, dom

I have a form, with a code to show a popup when I press a create/edit link. Now when I do a page refresh, I get the following popup
[image]

I have managed to stop the popup from appearing when Retry is pressed, by handling it on the code behind of my aspx, but when Cancel is pressed, the page blinks (I guess it renders again?) and the popup is shown.
It doesn't go back to the server. It just goes to the javascript function that displays the popup, and shows it.
It should be noted at this point that this popup is just a `<div>` which can be shown or hidden.The default property of this `<div>` is hidden. 
Please help me solve this issue and also explain why this is happening. I haven't been able to find anything on the internet explaining this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When submitting a form, content may be sent with either POST or GET.

Sending with GET appends values to the address defining what webpage you are on. It could look like this:

```
www.domain.tld/page?value1=apple&value2=banana
```

Sending with POST sends the value in a hidden field that the server receives.

Clicking "Retry" will load the website with the information currently held within the POST field. Clicking cancel should display the address you are heading to without the POST content.

I hope this answers your question. If not, is there any way for you to show the piece of code that handles the POST data?

Comment: But I am not going to a different page. It is on the same page. The popup is more like a div tag that is shown. It is not a separate window. So, there is no change in the address. I cannot show any code, but essentially under the click events, I am comparing my values in viewstate and session to determine if it was a refresh.

Comment: How are you handling the submitted POST content? If you are doing it with basic html `<form>`and `submit`, with a destination of the same page, you are still sending the POST information as I described above. Are you handling it with Viewstate?

Comment: I am using asp form, but yes. I am sending the data via POST. There is no query string. And the Retry button is handled using viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

The browser saves the data in the form when you submit it, and when you refresh the page, the browser attempts to send this data again. The popup is a warning from the browser that this is about to happen, which is important since the form could be on a shopping site, so resending the data would result in accidentally buying the same things multiple times.

To fix this, you can redirect to another page once the form has been submitted, or you can add code to reset the form so the data won't be sent again.

Comment: My question wasn't surrounding the data being sent again. I've already dealt with that. It was to do with what happens when I press cancel

Answer (score 0):

We should follow a best practice to solve this problem.  Better have a look at   [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). When you press the cancel button, it simply load the previous page and values will be persisted.

Comment: Considering my popup is just a <div> that gets shown on clicking the create button, clicking the close button hides it, and that is the last value that should persist, right? "display: none" should be the last value, but it calls the javascript that shows changes the display to block. How can that be?

Comment: are you setting the display:block on the post back success? or after the post back, user click on the Create button and to close it he clicked close button. Is that right?

Comment: On clicking create/edit, the post back success calls a javascript function that sets the display:block style. When user clicks on create/edit, a server request is made and after the response, the post back success is executed

Comment: Sorry. Can't do that

Answer (score 0):

My understanding so far is that when you press the cancel button, the values for the page is taken from the browser's cache. I cleared the cache to test this theory. The cache isn't just storing the values of the page but also the last server response received. In my case, the last server response was to show the the popup by calling my javascript function, along with the required values, which is what it did. 
Now my work around to it was to make the closing button as a server command as well, so that the final response would be to hide the popup.

Please do let me know if there is something wrong in this explanation.